# get child elements of a dictonairy

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a network with different hosts and different networks and I want to use ansible to ping each host in each network.

In my host_vars directory all informations about every host and its network are stored in its own file. A hostfile looks like this:

```yaml
bond:
  - conn_name: net1
    ip4: '10.10.44.21'
    gw4: '10.10.44.1'
  - conn_name: net2
    ip4: '10.10.47.21'
    gw4: '10.10.47.1'
  - conn_name: net3
    ip4: '10.10.46.21'
    gw4: '10.10.46.1'
bond_slave:
  - conn_name: eno1
    ifname: eno1
    master: net1
  - conn_name: eno2
    ifname: eno2
    master: net2
  - conn_name: ens2f1
    ifname: ens2f1
    master: net2
  - conn_name: ens2f0
    ifname: ens2f0
    master: net2
  - conn_name: ens4f1
    ifname: ens4f1
    master: net3
  - conn_name: ens4f0
    ifname: ens4f0
    master: net3
```

My purpose is to get every ip4-value and ping it from every host. what i can do is include all files from host_vars directory and ping the ip-adress of the first bond item of each file.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

- name: Include information about all hosts
  include_vars: ../../host_vars/{{ item }}.yaml
  with_items: hosts
  register: "r"

- name: execute ping
  command: ping {{ bond[0].ip4 }} -c 3
  with_items: "{{ r.results }}"
```

But the bond can have from 2 to 4 networks. How do i loop through each bond to access all ip-address?

**Solution**

Even though the snippet of Konstantin Suvorov wasn't working for me, it helped me to find the right solution:

```ansible
- name: execute ping
  command: ping {{ item.ip4 }} -c 3
  with_items: "{{ r.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.bond') | list }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `bond` var defined for each host via `host_vars`, you can use `hostvars` magic variable (no need to do this ugly include task):

```
- name: ping everything
  command: ping {{ item }} -c 3
  with_items: "{{ play_hosts | map('extract',hostvars,'bond') | list }}"
```

Actually this Jinja2 expression will return a list of lists, but `with_items` flattends them, so you end up with long list all elements from every bond of every host in current play.

Comment: thank you for your help. it helped me to find the correct syntax for the ping execution.